# how to add second table and get data from both tables in dataset in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, dataset

I m fetching data from database through c# to my asp.net file in dataset..
my c# code is like this:

```
{
Datalist a = e.Item.FindControl("abc") as DataList;
a.DataSource = GetData("select * from xyz where ID='" +((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem)).Row[0] + "' AND LIMIT 1");

a.DataBind();
}
```

Its working fine.. but i want to add another table to it.. means i want to data from two table of database..

I know how to do it with ExecuteReader() and Mysql Command.. but i dont know anythiong about this DataSource.. I am new to asp and c# so pls .. any help..
thank you so much

here that function GetData()

```
private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SpeedyFlower"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
      "SELECT * FROM employee1; SELECT * FROM employee2", connection);
adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "employee1");
adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "employee2");
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Now you have 2 tables in dataset ds as:

```
ds.Tables[0] //table employee1
ds.Tables[1] //table employee2
```

Put this code under GetData function (where you are makeing call to MySQLDataAdapter). In query just pass both the query for both the tables. Please note that TableMapping is optional and is not madatory.

Comment: hi, thank you so much answer.. but i know how to do this with adapter and reader.. but i don't know what is this DataSource and GetData().. can i use your answer and replace this things by your answer?

Comment: @nikunjramchandani: even i wonder what GetData() does but yes you can replace existing line with answer and then set datasource of datalist to ds.

Comment: I m really sorry.. but i found Getdata is a function and its transfer query to that function..

Comment: kindly provide snippet of Getdata

Comment: i m adding your code.. can you tell me that you do i need to use this "Table" and "Table1" any where??

Comment: i mean what changes i need to do in my asp page?

Comment: how to get this data on asp client page.. first table data is working but second not.. im using like this.. <%#Eval ("ID") %>...